# calling special form `set!` in a clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros

Given Java instance `obj` and a member name (string) `"Foo"`, and a map `conf`, I am trying to generate Clojure code that will look like this:

```clj
(if (get conf "Foo")
    (set! (.Foo obj) (get conf "foo")
    obj)
```

And also, if I know that `"SomeEnum"` is a Java enum name, a code like this:

```
(if (get conf "SomeEnum")
    (set! (.someEnum obj)(Enum/valueOf SomeEnum (get conf "SomeEnum")))
    obj)
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
(defmacro set-java [obj conf obj-name]
  `(if (get ~conf ~obj-name)
     (set! (. ~obj ~(symbol obj-name)) (get ~conf ~obj-name))
     ~obj))

(defn lowercase-first [s]
  (apply str (Character/toLowerCase (first s)) (rest s)))

(defmacro set-java-enum [obj conf obj-name]
  `(if (get ~conf ~obj-name)
     (set! (. ~obj ~(symbol (lowercase-first obj-name)))
           (Enum/valueOf ~(symbol obj-name) (get ~conf ~obj-name)))
     ~obj))
```

Testing with `macroexpand` seems to give the right result, but after trying:

```
(defn ^Policy map->policy [conf]
  (-> (Policy.)
      (set-java-enum conf "CommitLevel")
      (set-java conf "durableDelete")
      (set-java conf "expiration")
      (set-java conf "generation")
      (set-java-enum conf "GenerationPolicy")
      (set-java-enum conf "RecordExistsAction")
      (set-java conf "respondAllOps")))
```

I got a weird endless loop of reflection warnings.

--- edit ---

after battelling with that for quite a while, I gave up threading (`->`) and ended with:

```
(defmacro set-java [obj conf obj-name]
  `(when (get ~conf ~obj-name)
     (set! (. ~obj ~(symbol obj-name)) (get ~conf ~obj-name))))

(defn lowercase-first [s]
  (apply str (Character/toLowerCase ^Character (first s)) (rest s)))

(defmacro set-java-enum [obj conf obj-name]
  `(when (get ~conf ~obj-name)
     (set! (. ~obj ~(symbol (lowercase-first obj-name)))
           (Enum/valueOf ~(symbol obj-name) (get ~conf ~obj-name)))))

(defn map->write-policy [conf]
  (let [wp (WritePolicy. (map->policy conf))]
    (set-java-enum wp conf "CommitLevel")
    (set-java wp conf "durableDelete")
    ;; more non threaded object manipulation
    wp))
```

So I am still not sure what was the reflection warning endless loop about,  but this is hopefully handful as well, and can be improved further.

Comment: `(.foo X)` is a method call. Probably you want instance field access `(.-foo X)` instead.

Comment: @akond sharp eye! (documented [here](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_alternative_macro_syntax)) I fixed and edited the question, but it still goes into that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to your interpolating `~obj` multiple times in each macro. Is your "loop" actually endless, or is it just ~128 or ~256 steps long?

In any case, the fix for that particular issue (whether or not it's the root cause of the problem you describe) is to wrap the form in `(let [obj# ~obj] ...)` and then refer to `obj#` below, so the argument is only interpolated once.

You can (should!) do this with `conf` and `obj-name` too, but they're probably not actively causing problems, at least with the usage code you provided.

Comment: Another bug was that `set!` is inherently a special form that is not returning the result and only causes a side effect. so `~obj` should have been returned in that case also (in order thread the expression later.

Comment: in that case I think you want `doto` instead of `->`